# How to show error message if radiobittonlist is not selected?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new in c# programming
I have a radiobuttonlist(it contains two radiobuttons `employee` and `department`)and a dropdownlist. I want to show error message if I select dropdownlist without any of the radiobuttonlist selection. if there one radiobutton,we can use radiobutton.ckecked property. how can be done the same in the case of a radiobutton list? My design source is

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbllist"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
   RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="297px" 
  onselectedindexchanged="rbllist_SelectedIndexChanged">
   <asp:ListItem Text="Employee" Value="1" ></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Department" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:RadioButtonList>
  <table class="ui-accordion">


  <tr>

 <td align="left" class="style2">
 <asp:Label ID="lbldept" runat="server" Text="Department"></asp:Label></td>
 <td align="left">
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="dddept" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
 onselectedindexchanged="dddept_SelectedIndexChanged">
 </asp:DropDownList>
 </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>

 </td>
 </tr>
```

Is it right??

```
if (rbllist.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please select one radiobuttonlist filed ..!!');", true);
        }
```

Comment: Use a `CustomValidator` and add that logic to the [`ServerValidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.servervalidate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-event.

Comment: I agree with @TimSchmelter. But FYI, check the SelctedIndex property. if it is -1 then you know nothing has been selected.

Comment: @Ahmed ilyas, Please my edited answer..you mean like this??

Comment: Which asp.net version are you using? 4.0 + ?

Comment: @Siva Gopal..Asp.Net 4

Comment: @Ahmed ilyas, yes it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to first validate on client you can do following, since you are using ASP.NET 4

**Note**: It is a best practice to always validate on server side too, perhaps after Submit or a relevant event.

Set "ClientIDMode" to "Static" on the radiobuttonlist and dropdown as shown below:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbllist" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="297px"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbllist_SelectedIndexChanged" ClientIDMode="Static">

<asp:DropDownList ID="dddept" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
          OnSelectedIndexChanged="dddept_SelectedIndexChanged" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

You may use Javascript/Jquery for clientside check. But in Jquery you can check like following:

```
<script>
        $("select[id$=dddept]").click(function () {
            var isOneRadioSelected = false;
            $("#rbllist").find(":radio").each(function (index, radio) {
                isOneRadioSelected = radio.checked;
                if (isOneRadioSelected == true)
                    return false;
            });

            if (isOneRadioSelected == false) {
                alert("Please select atleast one radio button."); //Here you can do proper error display format based on your application requirement.
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `RequiredFieldValidator`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dddept" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
 onselectedindexchanged="dddept_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="-1" ID="Req_ID" Display="Dynamic" 
    ValidationGroup="g1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dddept"
    Text="*" ErrorMessage="Please Select Dept"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

OR

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dddept" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
 onselectedindexchanged="dddept_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0"/> 
<asp:ListItem Text="Value1" Value="1"/> 
</asp:DropDownList>


<asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="0" ID="Req_ID" Display="Dynamic" 
    ValidationGroup="g1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dddept"
    Text="*" ErrorMessage="Please Select Dept"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: I hope u didnt get ma question..Your answer is  for if i didnt select dropdown value. But am asking error message if clicked on dropdownlist without select any radiobutton value

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbllist"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
   RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="297px" 
  onselectedindexchanged="rbllist_SelectedIndexChanged">
   <asp:ListItem Text="Employee" Value="1" ></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Department" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:RadioButtonList> 
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator   
            ID="ReqiredFieldValidator1"  
            runat="server"  
            ControlToValidate="rbllist"  
            ErrorMessage="Select atleast anyone"  
            >  
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

try this...

Comment: it works only when click on submit button..I want error message when I click on dropdown box without any radiobuttonlist selection